# Bootstrap datetimepicker parsing data

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to parse hours and minutes from selected date&time.

```
var datetime = $('#datetimepicker').data('date');
```

gives: 2017-11-01 11:50

If I want to parse hours and minutes :

```
time = datetime.getHours()+':'+datetime.getMinutes();
```

error will occure : Uncaught TypeError: datetime.getHours is not a function.

Which functions to use, to parse data from date above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Date object:

```
var datetime = new Date($('#datetimepicker').data('date'));
var time = datetime.getHours()+':'+datetime.getMinutes();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split on `input` field data.

```
var time = datetime.split(" ")[1];
var hours = time.split(":")[0];
var minutes = time.split(":")[1];
```

Please let me know which library are you using so that I can give you exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your variable is date type. getHours() is a JS function for getting the hours from a date.

 Double check the type before. If is not, then you just parse the datetime string, using 
 `let minutes = parseInt(datetime.split(' ')[1].split(':')[0]);`